# IE wont fire my jquery's .click function. what could i do?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, click

okay i have the following code below:

SCRIPT:

```
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
      $(".header").click(function () {
   $(this).effect("bounce", { times:2 }, 200);
     $(".links").show("slow");
   });
 });
 </script>
```

HTML:

```
 <body>
   <div class="header">
     <p><img src="images/logo.png" width="438" height="131" alt="Larz Conwell" /></p>
     <p><span class="dash">//</span> Freelance Web Designer &amp; Graphic Artist</p>
   </div> 
   <div class="links">
   </div>
 </body>
```

and in IE it wont work at all, but it works on all the other browsers. what could be the problem?

also i tried another site i have with jquery on it and it works perfectly.

Comment: Try putting an `alert(1);` in the click callback and see if that happens when you click.

Comment: Are you including the jQ library?

Comment: Which version of IE?  IE sometimes wants the click on an anchor and nowhere else.

Comment: yess i am. like i said it works with other browsers, but for some reason it isnt in IE. i debugged it and it said "object expected" on the  $(document).ready(function() { line.

Comment: im using ie8. ill try that.

didnt work.

Comment: no it isnt its just jquery ui. theres nothing extra on it.

Comment: It works on IE8... could you check this link? [link](http://jsfiddle.net/joseadrian/pPWhn/1/)

Comment: thats weird. it worked there! :o

Comment: I used **jQuery 1.5** and **jQuery UI 1.8.10**

Comment: yeah i am too. ill just do something different i guess

Answer (score 1):

I think the javascript is getting executed even before the DOM is ready.
Try using $.live();

```
$('.header').live('click', function(){});
```

This would execute the event even if the class is created later in the DOM.

Comment: This saved me a world of pain this afternoon. +1.

Answer (score 0):

Are you absolutely certain you have jQuery referenced properly?  That is often the cause of an `object expected` error on `$(document).ready()`.  Using the code you've provided I am able to get IE 8 to fire the click event fine.  You can reference jQuery with the following:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" language="javascript"></script>
```

Comment: yeah i linked it correctly. and i tried it that way too, still nothing lol im not sure whats going wrong.

Comment: Do you have any other `<script>` tags on the page besides the jQuery reference and what you've pasted here?

Comment: nope the only script references i have are jquery and jquery ui.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
```

maybe you have noConflist in another script

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.header').click(function() {
$('.menu').show('slow', function() { 
      });
    });
   });
</script>
```

this is the code is used to fix it.